# comparing files which i created by python

Tags: python

I have created files using python, which I need to compare. How can I compare the two files using python?

```
def td():
    choice = input("which trainning event would you like to access?    
     \n1.swimming
     \n2.cycling
     \n3.running\nplease type in the number before the event of which you want to choose\n")
     if choice == "1":
            Swimming_file= open("Swimming_file.txt", "w")

        totaldistance = input("what was the total distance you swam in meters?")
        totaltime = input("how long did you swim for in minutes?")
        speed = totaldistance/totaltime
        print ("on average you where running at a speed of", speed, "mps")

        total = (totaldistance, totaltime, speed)
        Swimming_file.write(str(total))
        Swimming_file.close() 

elif choice == "3":
    Running_file= open("Running_file.txt", "w")


    totaldistanceR = int(input("what was the total distance you ran in KM?"))
    totaltimeR = int(input("how long did you run for in minutes?"))
    totaltimeR1 = 60/totaltimeR
    speedR1 = totaldistanceR/totaltimeR1

    print ("The records have been saved")
    print ("on average you where running at a speed of", speedR1, "KMph")

    totalR = (totaldistanceR, totaltimeR, speedR1)
    Running_file.write(str(totalR))
    Running_file.close()

elif choice == "2":
    Cycling_file= open("Cycling_file.txt", "w")

    totaldistancec = int(input("what was the total distance you ran in KM?"))
    totaltimec = int(input("how long did you run for in minutes?"))

    speedc = totaldistancec/totaltimec
    print ("on average you where running at a speed of", speedc, "KMph")

    totalc = (totaldistancec, totaltimec, speedc)
    Cycling_file.write(str(totalc))
    Cycling_file.close()
```

The created files contain running times named after the username. I need to compare files so the user can see how fast other users are.

I have been looking on the internet for this solution but none are relevant to my problem.

Comment: Can you give the file data which you have?

Answer (score 0):

I think you first need to update your question. if you would like to compare two files you can do it this way:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
with open(filename1) as f1:
   with open(filename2) as f2:
      if f1.read() == f2.read():
         ...
```

Or This way

```
import filecmp
if filecmp.cmp(filename1, filename2, shallow=False):
   ...
```

But you do not say what you would like clearly, what exactly are you comparing, are you comparing information inside the files with different username and times? How is the files structured. Do you need to select one user first and then find at what place sorted by time that user is compared to other?

We will help you just as long as you write an excellent description.

EDIT after OP updated post: You still need to give information about your data. and are you sure your code runs like you have written,

```
speed = totaldistance/totaltime
```

You should maybe not do math on a string. and you are not saving username in the file, how should you compare data without information about whom has what time in a certain event?

could you maybe write what you are trying to do so we can help you better?

Comment: I have now edited the question, I am comparing information in the files

Comment: Good, but there are still missing information. read my edit in my answer. maybe tell us what you want to be done, also if you want to compare you should also save information about whom has what times. There are multiple ways of doing this, you should firstly think about how to store your information so it can be read easily.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure about your question but i think this is your answer:

```
U1 = open('file1.txt', 'r')
U2 = open('file2.txt', 'r')
username1 = U1.readline()
username2 = U2.readline()
if U1.readline() >= U2.readline():
    #do something
else: 
    #do something else...
```